# onsharedpreferencechangelistener not work in android app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I wrote this code that works with sharedPreference ,
in sosbutton I changed sharedPreference  ,I want when sharedPreference changed ,
 onsharedpreferencechangelistener  fire .
I wrote this code but onsharedpreferencechangelistener  didn't fire.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         final    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("demopref", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            final Button sosBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            sosBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    String data = prefs.getString("demostring", "No Value");

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("demostring","HI...");
                    editor.commit();


            ////////////////////////////////
                }
                });        

            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"changed : " + key,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            };

            prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
        }

    }
```

please help me :(
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem:

```
  public class MainActivity  extends Activity {

        SharedPreferences pref;
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                if(key.equals("demopref"))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello2---"+key,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        };

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

        int i=0;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

            ////////////////////////////////////////

            final Button sosBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            sosBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("demopref","HI"+String.valueOf(i));
                    i++;
                    editor.commit();
                    /////////////////////////////////

                }
            });



        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            pref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

            super.onPause();
        }


    }
```

Comment: This worked really well

Answer (score 0):

`MODE_WORLD_READABLE` is deprecated, try `MODE_PRIVATE`

Comment: mmm... try to move `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {` etc outside the `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be help you...
your not given reference to your

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
```

**here is my code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     final    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final Button sosBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        sosBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                String data = prefs.getString("demostring", "No Value");

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("demostring","HI...");
                editor.commit();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

        ////////////////////////////////
            }
            });        

         listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"changed : " + key,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        };

        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

}
```